# Convert boot filesystem from xfs to ext4

Tags: filesystems, partition, ext4

I was wondering if it is possible to convert my boot system from xfs to ext4. If it is possible, how do I do so?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: @dr01 It is part of a requirement of an assignment that I have to have it as ext4 but I just only discovered that it is wrong

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this using [fstransform](https://github.com/cosmos72/fstransform), which is a tool to convert a filesystem type into another:

```
fstransform /dev/sda1 ext4
```

Currently it supports all main Linux filesystems i.e. ext2, ext3, ext4, jfs, ntfs, reiserfs, xfs.

Comment: If I execute this one then possibility to data loss ? If not then this is safe ?

Comment: There is always the possibility of data loss. Backup the data you cannot risk to lose. See the readme.md on GitHub.

Answer (score 1):

There is an old post on serverfault.com, hope you will find your answer here:

[changing filesystem format from xfs to ext4 without losing data](https://serverfault.com/questions/146123/changing-filesystem-format-from-xfs-to-ext4-without-losing-data)

To quote the top answer:

> i am unaware of any way to non-destructively convert a file system. this does not mean it is impossible, but i would put it at very low odds.
>
> you can, for example, convert from ext2 to ext3 without wiping the disk, and from ext3 to ext4.
>
> but to go from something like jfs to ext4 seems highly improbable, without first copying your `/home` files to another partition or external hard disk.
>
> even then, you would want to create a new user on your system, with a home directory somewhere like `/tmp/tempuser` or copy your configurations for your user, usually the 'dot' files (files beginning with .) in your home directory to a new location off /home and updating `/etc/passwd` to use the new home directory, so you can log in as a normal user while you're performing this update.
>
> then, back up your files, unmount `/home` and format it using `/sbin/mkfs.ext4` or whatever tool you plan to use. mount the fresh partition at /home and copy your files back.
>
> also, i would recommend something 'intelligent' like `rsync` to copy your files, to assure you preserve your permissions and all that jazz.

Answer (score -3):

Used fdisk to convert it.

```
fdisk /dev/sdb
```

Enter d (to delete a partition)

now fdisk /dev/sdb and create a partition

```
mkfs -t <filesystem_new> /dev/sdb
```

NOTE: This will result in data loss as we are deleting.